# PdfLaTeX: How to Add Space between Different Rows in a Table

Tags: tables, spacing

I'm confused about this problem, I want to add a space between different rows in a table, may I know if there is anyone who can solve it, thanks all in advance!

```
\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \caption{This is a caption.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} l l X @{} }
    \toprule
        Iterations & Samples & Comments \\
    \midrule
        0    & $\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png}$ & The text\\
        8    & $\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png}$ & The text\\
        16   & $\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png}$ & \\
        32   & $\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png}$ & \\
        64   & $\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png}$ & \\
        128  & $\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png}$ & \\
        192  & $\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png}$ & \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab4}
\end{table*}
```

Current result:

[image]

Comment: you can use `\\[1cm]` to get more space, also note you don't need to put `\includegraphics` in math mode

Comment: The `cellspace`  package enables you to define a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or any other letter you please if this is not possible).

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying them now, but it seems `\\[1cm]` only supports a space larger than 1 cm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert space between images on different ways. One, using `cellspace` package is mentioned in @Bernard comment, a next can be use of `\makegapedcells` defined in the `makecell` package. Since for vertical centering of rows content you use `adjustbox` package, you can exploit `margin` option defined in this package (see the second example). Another options is use of `tabularay` packafe for design of table. It insert vertical space (of 2pt) above/below cells contents, so you not need other measure for inserting vertical spaces between rows (see the first example below).

With use of `\adjincludegraphics` defined in the `adjustbox` package, defined common style options for images (since seems to have equal natural sizes)  and `tabularray` package, you can get:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\caption{This is a caption.}
\label{tab4}
    \adjustboxset{width=.6\textwidth, height=22mm, 
                  valign=c}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c, si={table-format=3}] Q[l] X[l,j]},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
{{{Iterations}}} 
    & Samples                           & Comments  \\
    \midrule
  0 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  & The text  \\
  8 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  & The text  \\
 16 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  &           \\
 32 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  &           \\
 64 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  &           \\
128 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  &           \\
192 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  &           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Similar result you get with `tabularx` package too. Using it, you need to add to `\adjustboxset` the option `margin`. All changes in compariso to the first example are in MWE below marked by `% <---`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx} % <---
\usepackage{siunitx}            % <---


\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\caption{This is a caption.}
\label{tab4}
    \adjustboxset{width=.6\textwidth, height=22mm,
                  valign=c, margin=0pt 2pt 0pt 2pt} % <---
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{S[table-format=3] l X}
    \toprule
\textbf{Iterations}                                           % <---  
    & \textbf{Samples}                  & \textbf{Comments}\\ % <---
    \midrule
  0 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  & The text  \\
  8 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  & The text  \\
 16 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  &           \\
 32 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  &           \\
 64 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  &           \\
128 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  &           \\
192 &  \adjincludegraphics{000000.png}  &           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Note: since in your code fragment you use `figure*` float environment, I conclude, that you use two column document. At it you not need positioning specification since it is always placed on the top of the next page where is inserted in text.

Comment: I like very much this table....This is goes into my bookmarks.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much!

Comment: It's very clear and useful, thanks!